# Given a real function $f(x)$ which is continuous, how can I show that $|f(x)|$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, proof-writing

Given a continuous, real function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$), how can I show that $|f(x)|$ is continuous?

This need not be done using a direct $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof, and may be done using sequences $x_n$ and the Algebra of Limits.

Comment: What have you tried already to solve this problem? Can you identify a definition for continuity using sequences?

Comment: More generally, the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that, by the triangle inequality,
$$||f(x)|-|f(y)||\leq |f(x)-f(y)|.$$

Comment: Thank you. How would one derive this from the standard rule for the triangle inequality (i.e. $|f(x) + f(y)| \leq |f(x)| + |f(y)|$)?

Comment: We have that $|f(x)|=|f(y)+(f(x)-f(y))| \leq |f(y)| + |f(x)-f(y)|$. Which implies $|f(x)|- |f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(y)|$. Swapping $x$ and $y$ you find also  $|f(y)|- |f(x)| \leq |f(x)-f(y)|$.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different idea: Suppose $|f|$ fails to be continuous at a point $y$. At this point, $f$ cannot be positive, because in a neighborhood of $y$ we would have $f = |f|$ by continuity of $f$. Nor can it negative, because in a neighborhood of $y$ we would have $-f = |f|$. Thus $|f(y)| = 0 = f(y)$. But $f(x_n) \to 0 = f(y)$ is clearly equivalent to $|f(x_n)| \to 0 = |f(y)|$ as $n \to \infty$, for any sequence $\{ x_n \}$ with $x_n \to y$. Thus $f$ is not continuous at $y$. This is a contradiction.